# iTerm2 - How to pass environment-variables when started via url-scheme?

Tags: macos, ssh, environment-variables, url-scheme, iterm2

## *Most of you certainly now the MacOS terminal emulator [iTerm 2](https://www.iterm2.com/)*

I want to pass my environment variables which I've set/saved in `~/.ssh/environment` to iTerm2, when it (the profile) is configured as default handler for this url-scheme. ( *ssh://==* )

---

## Normal example ← works

1. You open the app **iTerm2**
2. Enter your ssh-command:
   `ssh hostname`
3. It connects into your server and you can see with the command `printenv` your environment-variables you've put into your local `~/.ssh/environment` file.

## URL-Scheme example ← doesn't work

Some external application ( like the [alfred-ssh workflow](https://github.com/deanishe/alfred-ssh/) from [deanishe](https://github.com/deanishe)) can access your `.ssh/config` file to make it easier to access all your configured hosts quickly and opens them then via url-scheme.

1. Because **iTerm2** is configured for the ssh-scheme **iTerm2** starts and connects quickly to the server.
2. You enter `printenv` and doesn't find your environment-varialbes.

*You realize that **iTerm2** started instantly and doesn't loaded the local environment-variables. Okay, I doesn't realized this at the beginning and created an [issue](https://github.com/deanishe/alfred-ssh/issues/8) for the workflow I used. But the developer is right, iTerm2 starts and isn't able to load the environment variables.*

---

I've searched already several weeks for an solution, but wasn't able to solve this problem yet. That's why I'm asking here now.

## My local SSH  configuration (cleaned)

**Content of `~/.ssh/environment` is:**

```
echo "RMATE_HOST=localhost" > sshenv
echo "RMATE_PORT=52699" > sshenv
```

**Content of `~/.ssh/config` is:**

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    ServerAliveInterval 120
    TCPKeepAlive no
    UseKeychain yes
    SendEnv RMATE_*
    RemoteForward 52699 localhost:52699

Host personal
    HostName personal.tld
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyFileName1
    User user
    Port 22

Host work
    HostName business.tld
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/keyFileName2
    User user
    Port 22
```

And yeah, indeed! I just want to pass my RMATE variables to the servers via the workflow with [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/) ;-)